# As3: Where to start to learn how to use tile-based maps/code?

Tags: actionscript-3, resources, grid, editor, tile

I have searched the web for a good tutorial which teaches you the basics of making a map with tiles (XML).

I have searched for weeks and I have yet to find a good one that treats the student as a complete beginner.

I have watched a few videos, but none of them go from the start. I don't want to use anything like Flashpunk, as I want to LEARN how to do it myself.

TonyPa's tutorials only teach you how to use Arrays, but how do you learn how to translate an XML file into placing actual tiles on the stage? I'm so confused it hurts.

I have Tiled (the editor) and Flash cs6. Where do I start?

EDIT: I know how to work with 2D arrays, but not with XML (I want to make maps with a tile map editor)

BONUS QUESTION:

I tried your suggestion below, and the total code on the first frame is the following:

```
var map:Array = [
[1,1,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,1],
[1,1,1,1,1]
];

loadMap(map, 120);

function loadMap(map:Array, cellSize:int = 120):void
{
for(var row:int = 0; row < map.length; row++)
{
    for(var column:int = 0; column < map[row].length; column++)
    {
        var data:int = map[row][column];


        var object:Sprite;

        if(data === '0') object = new Bg();
        if(data === '1') object = new Ground();


        if(object !== null)
        {
            object.x = column * cellSize;
            object.y = row * cellSize;
            stage.addChild(object);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have two objects in the library, with the linkage names of "Bg" and "Ground".

I get the following errors:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 22  1176: Comparison between a value with static type int and a possibly unrelated type String.

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 22  1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Bg to an unrelated type flash.display:Sprite.

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 23  1176: Comparison between a value with static type int and a possibly unrelated type String.

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 23  1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Ground to an unrelated type flash.display:Sprite.
```

Answer (score 1):

For a beginner I would forget about XML and look at using 2D arrays. 2D arrays are great for 2D tile based maps because they offer exactly what you need - a 2 dimensional set of data. XML is overkill for this task in my opinion.

The anatomy of a 2D array is:

```
var map:Array = [ [] ];
//                ^^ An array inside the outer array.
```

Which is accessible as:

```
var inner:Array = map[0];
```

The syntax for accessing data in a nested array is to use consecutive `[]` access operators, so if that inner array contained some data like this:

```
var map:Array = [ [1] ];
```

You would use:

```
trace( map[0][0] ); // 1
```

Now, onto buildng a relationship between a 2D array and a 2D map. The concept behind the 2D array is that the index of the child arrays are rows (`y` position) and the index of the elements within those array represent columns (`x` position). This can be visualized easily by writing your level data like this:

```
var map:Array = [
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0]
];
```

This clearly represents a 3x3 level, and visually translates into how the map will actually be laid out when the data is read and translated into actual objects on the screen.

The data within those arrays act to represent what those objects on the map are. In a typical scenario, `0` would represent an empty tile on the map. We could use `1` to represent something like a Wall, and `2` to represent the player's starting position:

```
var map:Array = [
    [1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,0,0,1],
    [0,0,0,2,1],
    [1,0,0,0,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1]
];
```

This represents map where the outer edge is almost completely walled off, and the player starts near the top right.

As for actually working with that data, something like this will get you started:

```
function loadMap(map:Array, cellSize:int = 20):void
{
    for(var row:int = 0; row < map.length; row++)
    {
        for(var column:int = 0; column < map[row].length; column++)
        {
            var data:int = map[row][column];

            // Empty tile, move onto the next item.
            if(data === 0) continue;


            var object:Sprite;

            if(data === 1) object = new Wall();
            if(data === 2) object = new Player();

            if(object !== null)
            {
                object.x = column * cellSize;
                object.y = row * cellSize;
                stage.addChild(object);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to work with 2D arrays, but if I want to make bigger maps, I'd need a tile editor unless I wanted to spend hours typing in numbers..

Comment: @user3123633 It's easy enough to make an editor that translates item positions into this format. Anyway, you made it out that you were a complete beginner trying to understand basic tile data structure, not that you were trying to make an editor to develop comprehensive levels. If your concern is actually storing those 2D arrays, you can do that easily with `join` to save them and `split` to convert them back into arrays.

Comment: I meant I'm a complete beginner when it comes to handling xml (a.k.a translate it into an array format), how would I use "join" and "split" when it comes to XML? I don't want to make an editor, I want to use one (like Tiled)

Comment: Btw, I tried your code, and I updated the original post. Please have a look at it!

Comment: @user3123633 Sorry, somehow only just noticed this - it means your `BG` and `Ground` classes do not extend `Sprite`. I also accidentally used strings for the data bits, look at my update with a very minor fix.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the best sources about tiled-based games. It's a bit old, but it covers all the theory you need in order to start using tiles:

http://www.tonypa.pri.ee/tbw/index.html